# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error but server is set to *

Tags: ajax, http, postman

I'm trying to make a request to an API.  It works fine in postman, but not from the browser directly.  I can't find any difference between the 2 except https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.  But I don't understand why that would be a problem because the Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set to *.

Postman Preview:

```
GET /facebook/v1/api/v2.2/123585981029762/insights/page_impressions?period=day HTTP/1.1
Host: api.url.com
Authorization: Basic {BASIC AUTH HASH}
X-KO-ACCOUNT: 123585981029762
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Postman Response Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →    *
Cache-Control → private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Connection → keep-alive
Content-Length → 1000
Content-Type → application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date → Tue, 17 Mar 2015 21:51:17 GMT
ETag → "32a4e4fc7aeb25536a634c302505fb02e7efe9fb"
Expires → Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Facebook-API-Version → v2.2
Pragma → no-cache
X-FB-Debug → Y0OdHMjYO5KUIqcnnVNK4eWLZRiPSKUnsOAHZ3sf33qjVSanI2AoK/jpY9OhZUffGfX31Wo6IgUWMoXkZHZRKQ==
X-FB-Rev → 1645171
```

Javascript from Browser:

```
xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();   xmlhttp.open("GET","https://api.url.com/facebook/v1/api/v2.2/123585981029762/insights/page_impressions?period=day",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("authorization",'Basic {BASIC AUTH HASH}');
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-KO-ACCOUNT",'12358376954762');
xmlhttp.send();
```

Error Message (In Chrome):

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

Also, Chrome is showing an OPTIONS method instead of GET.  (I know that's normal with a cross-browser error) But the Remote Address IP is different.

ANY help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is very serious about this, and even by setting the headers to '*' it will not let you perform a cross-domain request.

What you can do for development mode is add " disable-web-security" in your chrome shortcut (after the path, by right-clicking -> properties). Then close every instance of Chrome in task manager, and double click the shortcut. You will get a warning that you started your browser in that mode, but then it should work for local testing purposes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot. Obviously domains talk to other domains all the time, so how should I set Access-control-allow-origin to allow it?

Comment: Some API's include an URI white list, which allows requests to specifically those domains. Depending on you situation you could also check 'jsonp', embed another website or use domain relaxation.

However, you could check if you can host the backend on the same origin.